# find auto change in next input type text in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, onchange

I have two inputs of type `text` which are interconnected.

Upon entering a value in the 1st textbox, the 2nd textbox is auto completed and populated with a value.

At the moment when the value in the 2nd textbox is changed, I want to get the value of the 2nd textbox using jQuery.

I have tried `.blur` and `.change` function but they are not getting called as desired.

Comment: share your code .... you can use `input` or `keypress` event

Comment: It might help, if you shared your code reduced to a minimal example which exhibits your behaviour. 'not getting called as desired' is also a bit vague.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyup function to detect changes as soon as it occurs. See sample code below..

```
$('#t1').keyup(function(){
   $('#t2').val($('#t1').val());
});
$('#t2').keyup(function(){
   $('#t1').val($('#t2').val());
});
```

Refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/31jqjy65/) for an example